# Redirect to clicked url with cookies.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, cookies

We normally use a prehome as the website of Forbes USA.

Every time we enter i.e. http://johnwho.url the page is redirected to a Welcome Home, and 8 sec later will be redirected to the original home , adding a cookie that will not show this pre-home again util 24 hores later.

like:

```
//Redirect
welcome = function() {
    var cookie_name = 'welcome';
    var value = true;
    var go = Cookies.get(cookie_name);


    if (go == null) {
        Cookies.set(cookie_name, value, {  expires: 1, path: '/' });
        window.location = "/bienvenidos/"
    } else  {
        return false;
    }

}

window.onload =  welcome();
```

But what if we want to redirect site wide, from an article or different url.

how can we change the redirect path to the selected(clicked) url??

What would be the best option to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways: first you store all URLs which used to redirect into DB and use GET attributes which contains id from DB, another idea use GET attribute, which store URL.

For first solution URL looks like http://example.com/redirect/?urlID=100,

for the second issue -> http://example.com/redirect/?url=http://my-anothersite.example.com